# Power and footnote ? Question of aesthetics

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I need to use a footnote immediately after "χ²"

Unfortunately, this produces "χ²²" in my final text, as the font and fontsize for the power of 2 (^2) is exactly the same than the footnote font and fontsize.

Has anyone already have that kind of issue and have an idea on how to make this all nicer to look at ?

This will be printed and read in print as well as .pdf and I don't want the .... most exhausted or less aware readers to think I've written "χ²²".

I tried putting  χ² in bold as it figures in a "normal" text environment, but it does not seem to work.

TL;DR : aesthetic way to differentiate "χ²" with the "²" of the footnote? (I'd prefer not to change all my footnote to roman numerals or letters)

Comment: Your approach has some issues. Suppose you just change the visual of the problematic footnote-mark, it will be inconsistent with the others which itself is a big turn off for aesthetics according to many. Suppose you consistently reduced the size of all the footnote-marks for this particular case, that too will not look good in front of normal characters. In my humble opinion, the best way is to try and edit the text to fit the limitations of the writing conventions itself. This is not a problem specific to TeX, but an ambiguity in the writing conventions. We have to adjust...

Comment: You wrote, "I need to use a footnote [marker] immediately after χ²". Is something stopping you from rephrasing the sentence in question so that "χ²" occurs somewhere in the middle of the sentence and the footnote marker can be placed at the end of the sentence?

Comment: χ² is already at the end of the sentence, and I was asked to provide a footnote defining what χ² means. I could eventually write "χ² (khi square)\footnote{}" if there is no other way... I agree with you @Niranjan this is an adjustment situation... What is stressful for me here is that my readers will not be familiar with any kind of mathematical notation including powers... and χ² is already considered "complex" for them LOL

Comment: Add hyperref package so the footnote marker is coloured. But in general you should rephrase.

Comment: Using colors could indeed help. Instead of coloring the footnote marker, you can alternatively color the math expression. Or you can put it inside quote marks to separate it more from the footnote. Nevertheless, this is a general typography question and also opinion based. It is not a TeX question. Therefore it is IMHO off-topic.

Comment: If your readers are already expected to be unfamiliar with the chi^2 notation, would an alternative option be to define the notation **inline** instead of in a footnote? Like ".... chi^2 (this symbol stands for ....)."

Comment: Golden rule: never footnote math. Changing the marker to have reduced size is to no avail, because the superscript will be read as, say, “2 sub 3”. Changing to Roman numerals would be likely misinterpreted, besides you not really wanting footnote markers such as “xviii”. There is *always* a way to rephrase.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has commented, I think everyone agrees that the best solution would be to rephrase and I'm going to do that. I agree that this was not *essentially* about TeX (but I was opened to a TeX solution so I asked anyway).